# Debugging Typescript with Visual Studio Code and separate output folder

Tags: debugging, typescript, visual-studio-code, breakpoints

How to compile typescript code to a different folder while still being able to debug the code?

Assume I want to set a breakpoint on the first `console.log` in file `myapp.ts`:

```
class HelloTS {
    public static main(): number {
        console.log('Hello TS');

        console.log("about to exit now")
        return 0;
    }
}

HelloTS.main();
```

and the following `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

Breakpointing works fine as long as `myapp.ts`, `myapp.js`, and `myapp.js.map` are in the same folder.

However, when I create separate folder for sources (`src/`) and output (`dist/`), breakpointing does not work and does not throw any error either.

I have the following config, which compiles successfully, but fails to provide debugging.

`.vscode/tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [
        "-p", ".", 
        "--rootDir", "src/", 
        "--outDir", "dist/"    
    ],
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "echoCommand": true,
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

`.vscode/launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/myapp.ts",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "preLaunchTask": null,
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy"
            ],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outFiles": [
                "**/*.js",
                "**/*.js.map"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5858,
            "address": "localhost",
            "restart": false,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outFiles": [],
            "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "remoteRoot": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command.PickProcess}",
            "port": 5858,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outFiles": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `outFiles` attribute in your `launch.json` should be:

```
{
  ...

  "outFiles": [ "${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*" ]

  ...
},
```